# Insert a row for indexing a Dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, insert

I have a dataframe thats rows are indexed properly 1:n but the columns do not have an integer index. the first row represents frequencies, which are not actual integers allowing for easy indexing.

heres what im looking at:

| index | 3.14 | 3.28 | 3.42 | 3.56 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | data | data | data | data |
| 1 | data | data | data | data |
| 2 | data | data | data | data |
| 3 | data | data | data | data |
| 4 | data | data | data | data |

heres what i want:

| index | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3.14 | 3.28 | 3.42 | 3.56 |
| 1 | data | data | data | data |
| 2 | data | data | data | data |
| 3 | data | data | data | data |
| 4 | data | data | data | data |
| 5 | data | data | data | data |

I have this ready, but need to find an insert function that also will alllow me to convert the array into a df

```
 ### df size = [20000, 100]
 index_row = np.linspace(1,100,100)
 index_row = index_row.reshape(1,100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reset_index` after tranposing your df.

Let's load a sample of your data:

```
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO(
"""
    3.14    3.28    3.42    3.56
0   data    data    data    data
1   data    data    data    data
2   data    data    data    data
3   data    data    data    data
4   data    data    data    data
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data,delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0)
```

Then use this

```
df.transpose().reset_index(drop = False).transpose().reset_index(drop = True)
```

to produce this

```
           0       1       2       3
0       3.14    3.28    3.42    3.56
1       data    data    data    data
2       data    data    data    data
3       data    data    data    data
4       data    data    data    data
5       data    data    data    data
```